# Why does Spotify say that there is no Internet connection available when there is one (Samsung Galaxy S)?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, connection-issues, spotify

When I start the Spotify Android app from my Samsung Galaxy 1 it seems that the internet connection is not working:

[image]

What can I do to resolve this?

Comment: Have you asked on the Spotify Community?

Comment: I'm still having this issue with Wifi on a Galaxy S4.

Comment: This happens on the desktop client as well. Spotify's code for detecting network connection must give up permamently after a period of time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lucky for you, I am a super user on the Spotify community.

First, you need to wipe the data for the Spotify app, and then re login.

Once this has done, it may take a few seconds for the app to recognise the Internet connection.

If that fails to work, reinstall the app, and login again.

Answer (score 3):

I just went through the same issue. 
Definitely solved now.

At first I had a very bad connection speed even on H+ or 3G. On spotify app the "bad connection" problem turned to "no connection" so I decided to investigate.

The problem was my network AP which was configured over "WAP" which is not a real full featured Internet connection.
So I had to switch to the good AP (I've had to create a new one).

I did so on Android ICS like this :

1. went to : Settings > More... (Wireless and network) > Mobile Networks > Access Point Names
2. Switch my AP : I only had "WAP" and "MMS". None of these two are recommended for spotify app which doesn't use HTTP protocol to stream data. So I created a new one named "Internet" and filled in the settings page with informations found on my network provider support page (I am in France so my settings won't be suitable for you)

Now spotify works great + I have a new blasting Internet connection for all the other apps !!!

Hope it helps